# Render js.erb view on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view in the file APP/views/js/library.js.erb file, it contains:

```
bar: <%= raw @foo %>
```

On Rails 4 I got the content of that view using:

```
av = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app', 'views'))
av.assign({ foo: my_dynamic_variable })
av.render(template: 'js/library')
```

but on Rails 6 I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `html_fallback_for_js' for 
"app/views/js/library":String
from /home/manuel/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/actionview- 
6.1.4.1/lib/action_view/base.rb:264:in `in_rendering_context'
```

Comment: Thats a very fancy way of doing `"bar: #{@foo}"`.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 6.1:

```
lookup_context = ActionView::LookupContext.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths)

context = ActionView::Base.with_empty_template_cache.new(lookup_context, {}, nil)

renderer = ActionView::Renderer.new(lookup_context)

renderer.render(context, { file: 'app/views/template.html.erb' })
```

- `ActionView::Renderer.new()` takes a `lookup_context` arg, and `render()` method takes a context, so we set those up first
- `ActionView::Base` is the default `ActiveView` context, and must be initialized with `with_empty_template_cache` method, else `render()` will error
- The `{}`, `nil` are required assigns and controller args, which used to default `to {}`, `nil` in Rails 5
- Rails 6.1 requires a full filepath file: 'app/views/template.html', whereas Rails 5 only required the filename

Answer (score 2):

This is the new way:

```
 ApplicationController.render(template: '/js/library.js.erb',
 locals: { categories: 'categories', periods: 'periods' },
 assigns: assigns,  handlers: [:js],  formats: [:js] )
```

Comment: how to include helpers?