# undefined method `html_fallback_for_js' in ActionView::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have recently upgraded a project to `ruby 3.2.2` and `rails 6.1`
I am having issues with `ActionView::Base`. With the recent upgrade, I need to pass 3 arguments to `ActionView::Base.new` instead of 2. From the docs, `ActionView` now receives `lookup_context, assigns, controller`

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(
  ActionController::Base.view_paths, 
 {
  client: client,  
  report: self.report, 
},
nil
)
```

So I fixed it by passing `nil` (as shown above), but now I get a different error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/actionview-6.1.7.3/lib/action_view/base.rb:264:in `in_rendering_context': undefined method `html_fallback_for_js' for #<ActionView::PathSet:0x0000000110898f58 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000010fa92670 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000000110898f30 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x0000000110898eb8>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x0000000110898e90 keys=0 queries=0>, @path="/Users/Mari/reporting/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000010fa92760 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00000001108994a8 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x0000000110899408>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00000001108993e0 keys=0 queries=0>, @path="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/graphiql-rails-1.9.0/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000010fa92850 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000000110899ac0 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x0000000110899a48>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x0000000110899a20 keys=0 queries=0>, @path="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/teaspoon-1.2.2/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000010fa92940 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000000110899e80 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x0000000110899e08>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x0000000110899de0 keys=0 queries=0>, @path="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/devise-security-0.18.0/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000010fa92990 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x000000011089a268 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x000000011089a1f0>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x000000011089a1c8 keys=0 queries=0>, @path="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/devise-4.8.0/app/views">, #<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x000000010fa929e0 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x000000011089a740 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x000000011089a6c8>, @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x000000011089a650 keys=0 queries=0>, @path="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/ckeditor-4.3.0/app/views">]> (NoMethodError)

      if !lookup_context.html_fallback_for_js && options[:formats]
```

The `actionview` version is `6.1.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6.1 `ActionView::Base.new` takes [3 arguments](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/90b0266e9bfaaadbd2d249ad2eeec042077a0063/actionview/lib/action_view/base.rb#L230): lookup_context, assigns, controller

But you passed `ActionView::PathSet` instance instead of `ActionView::LookupContext`

This object hasn't such [getter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/90b0266e9bfaaadbd2d249ad2eeec042077a0063/actionview/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb#L124), that's why you have error

Instead of this wrap path set into lookup context. Also in new Ruby don't need duplicate value if it's name is equal of key name

```rb
view =
  ActionView::Base.new(
    ActionView::LookupContext.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths),
    { client:, report: },
    nil,
  )
```

After that you can use this view for rendering

Comment: Thanks! Almost what I needed. I also had to change ActionView::Base.new to ActionView::Base.with_empty_template_cache.new

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011135/render-js-erb-view-on-rails-6)

I have changed the call from `ActionView::Base.new` to `ActionView::Base.with_empty_template_cache.new`

and also one of the arguments from context to a `LookupContext` like this:
from `ActionController::Base.view_paths` to `ActionView::LookupContext.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths)`

the call now looks like this:

```
   view = ActionView::Base.with_empty_template_cache.new(
      ActionView::LookupContext.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths), 
     {
      client: client, 
      report: self.report, 
    }, nil
    )
```